# Swift app Google Sheets update 405 or 404

Tags: swift, google-sheets

I've been trying to code an App to update a simple Google Sheet.
One row three cells. 'Name', Integer, Date.
I've met nothing but problems.
I know that there are genious experts inside this forum and that's why I ask if someone could spare a moment to help me, pls.

---

Now I'm getting 401 'UNAUTHENTICATED' and 'CREDENTIALS_MISSING'
I opend a new Google Sheets sheet with no project configured in Google Console. Just a sheet and I shared it publicli editable.
I don't understand what kind of authentication it wants?
Could someone advise me pls.

My project's Podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '16.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
#  pod 'GoogleSignInSwiftSupport'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST'
  pod 'SwiftSpreadsheet'
  pod 'Auth0'
  pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Sheets'
  pod 'GTMAppAuth'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

And the Class I call like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import GoogleSignIn
import GoogleAPIClientForREST
import Auth0
import Alamofire


class ViewController3: UIViewController {
    
    private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets]
    private let service = GTLRSheetsService()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        let baseUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d"
        let spreadsheetId = "121212121212121212121212121212121212/"
        let range = "BlueBook!A3:C3"
        
        let params = [
        "Values": [
            ["Name", 50, "\(Date.self)"],
            [range]
        ]
    ]

        let requestURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/\(spreadsheetId)/values/\(range)"
        
        let hed = ["Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
  
    //         let requestURL = baseUrl + "/" + spreadsheetId
  
        print("requestURL: \(requestURL)")

        let req = AF.request(requestURL, method: .put, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: HTTPHeaders(hed))
                req.responseString { response in debugPrint(response) }
    }
}
```

With requesrURL the result is 404 and if I leave values and range away it will be 405.

Comment: May I know if your Spreadsheet access permission is "Anyone with a link"?

Comment: Thank You for your reply. Yes I have that choosen.

Comment: Try replacing the `requestURL = `[`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/\\(spreadsheetId)/values/\\(range)`](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/%5C\(spreadsheetId\)/values/%5C\(range\)) this URL is specifically for the Google Sheets API v4.

Comment: Thank You for your answer! It helped me a lot closer to solution, but now I'm getting 401. Something about authentication. I have 'All who have the link' as moderator chosen.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the error 401 seems to be related to your authentication process, but it looks like the issue in your comment is a new issue that is different from your original question. So, I'd recommend posting it as a new question instead. Because, when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it. Make sure you provide your authentication code on the new post.

Comment: Moreover, I'll post the last comment as an answer to this post so that other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that the request URL that returns 404 can be resolve by replacing the URL format.

Comment: Now I get 'CREDENTIALS MISSING' 401

Comment: You may consider checking this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015529/how-to-write-to-google-sheets-in-swift?rq=3

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the `requestURL =` [`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/\\\\(spreadsheetId)/values/\\\\(range)`](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/%5C%5C(spreadsheetId)/values/%5C%5C(range)) will fix the error 404 because this URL is specifically for the Google Sheets API v4.